# I can't work out what's wrong with this policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to allow cross account access for our CRM to be able to upload reports directly. I do not have access to the other account but I am assuming that they have created an IAM role, but no reports are being uploaded!!!

This is the policy I have created:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1678295199232",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1678295196150",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::093535234988:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tigerstwocircles/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Upload reports to S3 bucket

Comment: You should probably go and talk to the team that's attempting to upload to this bucket. Are your assumptions about their IAM permissions correct? What symptoms are they seeing? You might also consider enabling [S3 Bucket Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) on this bucket to ensure you own the uploaded objects (if that's your intention).

Comment: Thanks @jarmod  I am about 90% sure that they have set up an IAM but yes, I will be speaking to them. I have bucket owner enforced enabled ownership too :)